# JavaFX: How do I track the information of a pixel over which the user's mouse is currently hovering inside an ImageView?

Tags: user-interface, image-processing, model-view-controller, javafx

## What I'm trying to accomplish:

Some cool image browsing applications have a status bar at the bottom of the app that constantly displays information of the pixel you are currently hovering over. Information such as X and Y position, RGB data and sometimes even the color's hex code.

## What I've done:

So the model and the view parts of MVC are easy for me. I created a model class that holds a `SimpleStringProperty` to which I will attach a listener in the `StatusBarView` Controller.

In SceneBuilder I've bound the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseMoved` events of the `ImageView.fxml` to a method in the `ImageViewController` called `mouseHoverInfo`. It's an empty method and I don't know what to put in there. I did a deep Google and it seems that JavaFX doesn't allow for pixel information mouse hoverage tracking?

## The Pseudocode

The body of the following method is Java-esque pseudocode to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do in the method declaration in the `ImageViewController`.

```
@FXML
private void mouseHoverInfo() {

    ImageViewInternalMouseHoverTracker ivimht = new ImageViewInternalMouseHoverTracker(this.imageView);

    String xPos = ivimht.getX();
    String yPos = ivimht.getY();
    String colorRed = ivimht.getR();
    String colorBlue = ivimht.getG();
    String colorGreen = ivimht.getB();
    String hexColor = ivimht.getHex();

    String pixelInfo = "X: " + xPos + " Y: " + yPos + " | " 
            + "r: " + colorRed + " g: " + colorGreen +
            " b: " + colorBlue + " | " + hexColor;

    mainApp.getPixelInfo().setInfoString(pixelInfo);
}
```

Comment: The [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) passed to the mouse moved handler has the coordinates.

Comment: @James_D Hello, James! You also commented in my `ImageViewPane` question. Good to see you again. How do I access the coordinates from inside the method? I'm using SceneBuilder to bind the fxml with the controllers.

Comment: Just call `getX()` and `getY()` on the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution:

Thanks for the pointer, @James_D! Here's the complete event handling for a mouse hover pixel information tracker (had to use a little bit of AWT).

```
this.imageView.setOnMouseMoved(event -> { try {

            // AWT Robot and Color to trace pixel information
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int) event.getScreenX(), (int) event.getScreenY());

            // Initializing pixel info
            String xPos = Integer.toString((int) event.getX());
            String yPos = Integer.toString((int) event.getY());
            String colorRed = Integer.toString(color.getRed());
            String colorBlue = Integer.toString(color.getBlue());
            String colorGreen = Integer.toString(color.getGreen());
            String hexColor = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue());

            // Unify and format the information
            String pixelInfo = "X: " + xPos + " Y: " + yPos + " | "
                    + "r: " + colorRed + " g: " + colorGreen +
                    " b: " + colorBlue + " | " + hexColor;

            // Pass it on to the MainApp
            this.mainApp.getPixelInfo().setInfoString(pixelInfo);

        } catch (Exception ignore){}});
```